# Сохранение содержания div в картинку

Tags: javascript, html

Есть `<div id="construct"></div>` в который добавляются всякие картинки по скриптам.
Можно ли сохранить содержимое этого div в картинку .png или .jpg?
Смотрел в сторону canvas, но там через php. Через javascript можно так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать скриншот или отрисовку элемента нативными средствами браузера из JS нельзя. Можно только имитировать, воссоздавая изображение на канвасе, или другими обходными путями.

Один из вариантов - использовать JS библиотеку [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: получается, только через php можно?

Comment: @votanko зачем php? Я же написал что на JS библиотека

Comment: Понял, буду ковырять

Comment: @votanko Если вам именно из браузера на диск нужно сохранить, то тогда да, нужно какой-то серверный язык использовать или делать полноценное приложение, потому что браузер сам не может сохранить на диск. Но можно делать кнопку скачивания картинки на JS без серверного языка.